# JavaFX FXML constructor and initialize method

Tags: javafx

I'm new to javafx recently,and I always load fxml in the constructor of controller class then use components directly.

I have just learned that the components can only be accessed before initialize was called.

But it's very weird even i use component just in constructor there are no error occur.
My code look like this.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    new MainController(primaryStage,this);
}


public class MainController{
    @FXML
    private ListView<HistoryPlay> historyLV;
public MainController(Stage primaryStage, Main main) {

        initFxml();
        initView();


}
private void initFxml() {
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setController(this);
        try {
            loader.setLocation(new File("fxml\\Main.fxml").toURL());
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

private void initView() {

        historyLV.setCellFactory(param -> new HistoryListCell(MainController.this,main));
        historyLV.setItems(main.getHistoryManager().getHistoryList());


    }

}
```

There are no null point exception occur.Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `public` fields and non-`public` fields with the `@FXML` annotation with names which match an `fx:id` are initialized by the `FXMLLoader` in your assigned controller class (using `FXMLLoader.setController(Object)`) when the `FXMLLoader.load()` method is invoked.

So it can be assumed (since it is not included in your question) that you have a `ListView` in your FXML file `Main.fxml` with `fx:id="historyLV"`. This is why you do not get `NullPointerException`.